How to connect securely to Elasticsearch with existing certificates?
I installed Elasticsearch cluster on my own servers. it has a couple of certificates like http_ca.crtm http.p12 and transport.p12 in its certs folder.
These certificate installed on server by Elasticsearch.
look at configuration:
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

Now, I want to connect to my Elasticsearch from different sources such as Jaeger. but I dont know how to serve correct certificate to established connection securely.
Actually I dont know about the certificates. I dont know which of them is for client and which of them is for server.
I tried to disable tls verification but this option is not available in all issues.

There are two types of certificates in Elasticsearch.

Intranode certificates
Client certificates.

Intranode certificates (transport) can be generated with
bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca
ENTER ENTER
bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
ENTER ENTER ENTER

and these can be set in elasticsearch.yml
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12

You can use the same certificates as client certificates. Then you need to add:
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication: optional

Here is a nice source: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-security-configure-tls-ssl-pki-authentication
This is also worth to read:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/generates-self-signed-client-certificates-not-server-certificates-for-elasticsearch-clients/352182

In addition to the information outlined in this answer, it should also be noted that whichever way ElasticSearch is configured to serve over SSL, client connections to the Cluster will also likely have to know to trust the Certificate Authority used to sign the ElasticSearch certificate. Here's some helpful information on how to update your CA Trust store
